# How can I draw and pick Z axis of Isometric tiles in VC++/Win32 API?

Tags: isometric

I've finished draw Isomeric tiles with X, Y axis.

But I want to express Z axises.

How can I draw Z axis of Isometric tiles?

## My code is like this.

```
//tiles
_center.x = (_id.x - _id.y) * TILEWIDTH_HALF;
_center.y = (_id.x + _id.y) * TILEHEIGHT_HALF;

//picking
x = ((_ptMouse.y - _offSet.y) + (_ptMouse.x - _offSet.x) / 2) / TILEHEIGHT;
y = ((_ptMouse.y - _offSet.y) - (_ptMouse.x - _offSet.x) / 2) / TILEHEIGHT;
```